# Google Analytics & vanity urls?

Tags: url, vanity-url

Is there a way to use Google Analytics to track vanity urls that redirect to other site locations?

Like this:
http://www.focusonenergy.com/utilities

Resolves to:
http://www.focusonenergy.com/about/participating-utilities

I'd like to know how many visitors used the vanity link. Filtering the Site Content doesn't give an accurate report.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can, but you need to decorate your vanity link href with additional meta details if you have control of it, or you'd need to track the URL hit server side before you redirect the user. I believe the Analytics has an API you can call from your server side code.